# Resize divs on slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like the .left div (width:20%;) to slide into the .right div (initial width:100%;) and have the .right div resize on animation to width:80%;

Basically, slide in a div and have the other resize.

http://jsfiddle.net/LTUTR/

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="left">
    <p>left</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p>right content</p>
    <p class="showLeft">[Show left div]</p>
</div>
```

​

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left, .right {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.left {
    background: green;
    width: 20%;
    display: none;
}

.right {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.showLeft {
    cursor: pointer;
}
​
```

JS

```
$('.showLeft').click(function(){
    $('.right').animate({width: '80%'},350);    
    $('.left').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, `width:'toggle'` doesn't exist</s>...Actually, it exists! It's [in the specs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding
>   and showing animations that take into account the display type of the
>   element.

I really don't know why it's not working here. And `show` seems buggy ([little flashy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/vUka6/1/)).

Anyway, you can set the initial width to 0:

```
.left {
    background: green;
    width:0;
    display: none;
}
```

And use this edited function:

```
$('.showLeft').click(function(){
        $('.right').animate({width: '80%'},350);
        $('.left').css('display','block').animate({width:'20%'},350);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/vUka6/)

Comment: No hiding of a div.  I'm sorry if I didn't word correctly, but this is perfect!

Comment: Then it's OK :) I thought the `toggle` means it should actually toggle the green one

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code to smoothly animate back and forth.  We're just looking at the width of the left div to decide how to proceed
`code`http://jsfiddle.net/marktoth/W7UwU/7/

Comment: You should include the code in your answer, not just post a fiddle link.

Comment: Much better! That's what I was looking for. I agree with Mark. Please add the code to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.showLeft').toggle(function(){
    $('.right').animate({width: '80%'},350);    
    $('.left').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
},
function(){
    $('.right').animate({width: '100%'},350);    
    $('.left').animate({width:'toggle'},350);
});
```